# How to add Qbutton to the page without designing?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i'm new in QT. I develop a program that need `1024 line` that each line have two buttons , two radio buttons and two lalbes. i have two way for that.

1. in designer mode i drag and drop 2 * 1204 buttons , 2*1024 labels and 2*1024
       radio buttons that it is illogical.
2. there is a way that without designer mode and drag and drop add this widgets
       to the page for example in the run time i click on a button and in code-behind 
       add this widgets(labels,buttons,radio buttons) to the page or some thing like this.

i did second way in the web programming. is this possible in QT? or some thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create widgets programmatically and adjust their positions via layouts.
For example, it might look like so:

```
QVBoxLayout *topLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

for (int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < 1024; ++lineNumber)
{
    QWidget *oneLineWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QHBoxLayout *oneLineWidgetLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    { //added these brackets just for the ease of reading.
        QLabel *labFirst = new QLabel(tr("first label"), oneLineWidget);
        QLabel *labSecond = new QLabel(tr("second label"), oneLineWidget);
        QPushButton *bFirst = new QPushButton(tr("first button"), oneLineWidget);
        QPushButton *bSecond = new QPushButton(tr("second button"), oneLineWidget);
        QRadioButton *rbFirst = new QRadioButton(tr("first radiobutton"), oneLineWidget);
        QRadioButton *rbSecond = new QRadioButton(tr("second radiobutton"), oneLineWidget);

        oneLineWidgetLayout->addWidget(labFirst);
        oneLineWidgetLayout->addWidget(labSecond);
        oneLineWidgetLayout->addWidget(bFirst);
        oneLineWidgetLayout->addWidget(bSecond);

        //lets put one radioButton under another. 
        QVBoxLayout *radioButtonsLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        {
            radioButtonsLayout->addWidget(rbFirst);
            radioButtonsLayout->addWidget(rbSecond);
        }
        //and now we can combine layouts.
        oneLineWidgetLayout->addLayout(radioButtonsLayout);

    }
    oneLineWidget->setLayout(oneLineWidgetLayout);

    topLayout->addWidget(oneLineWidget);
}

this->setLayout(topLayout);
```

There are different types of layouts (QBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QFormLayout, etc.) that you can play with. You can start from [QLayout documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html). There is a list of classes that inherit it.
I hope that it will help! :) Good luck!

Comment: P.S. I wrote it in the notepad and didn't test "in real life". So it probably contains some errors. But at least I hope that it will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

All you do in Qt Designer is eventually translated to C++ code creating objects and linking them to each other.

So it is quite trivial to take that code (have a look at the generated header file) and put it into a for loop. Or even start over by yourself, creating three buttons and adding them to a layout are just a couple lines of code.